# TS error: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<any> due to withRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am getting this error

> client:159 [at-loader] ./src/App.tsx:40:46 
>       TS2322: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent | ComponentClass | ComponentClass, any> | FunctionComponent> | undefined'.
>     Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent>'.

On this component:

```
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import User from './scenes/user/User';

const store = configureStore();

type IsOpen = boolean;

const App: FC = () => {
  const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState<IsOpen>(false);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Sidebar
          open={sidebarOpen}
          sidebar={<PrimaryNav closeNav={() => setSidebarOpen(false)} />}
          onSetOpen={setSidebarOpen}
          styles={{ sidebar: { background: 'black' } }}>
          <Header sidebarOpen={sidebarOpen} onSetSidebarOpen={setSidebarOpen} />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path='/' component={NewsArticles} />
            <Route exact={true} path='/user' component={User} />
            <Route path='/user/:id' component={User} />
          </Switch>
        </Sidebar>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

On this two lines

```
            <Route exact={true} path='/user' component={User} />
            <Route path='/user/:id' component={User} />
```

Here is the user component:

```
import React, { FC, useEffect } from 'react';

import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

type Props = {
  match: any;
  history: any;
  location: any;
  withRouter: any;
  fetchUsers?: any;
  users?: UserInfoModel[];
};

const mapState = (state: UsersAppState, props: Props) => {
  return {
    users: state.usersReducers.users,
    ...props
  };
};

const actionCreators = {
  fetchUsers
};

const User: FC<Props> = props => {
  const { history, users, location, match, fetchUsers } = props;

  const setID = match.params.hasOwnProperty('id') ? match.params.id : 'AbedA';

  const handleFetch = () => {
    return fetchUsers(setID);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!users || !users.length) {
      handleFetch();
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleFetch();
  }, [location.pathname, match.params.id]);

  return (
    <UserContainer history={history} fetchUsers={() => fetchUsers(setID)} users={users} profilePicture={profileImg} />
  );
};

export default compose(
  connect(
    mapState,
    actionCreators
  ),
  withRouter
)(User);
```

Every single thing I put regarding `react-router/react-router-dom` comes with an error.

If I remove `withRouter` the errors are gone.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried using typescript assertion https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html. so you could say `User as FunctionComponent` (not tested)

Answer (score 4):

You can solve the error like this:

```
export default compose<React.ComponentType<Props>>(
  connect(
    mapState,
    actionCreators
  ),
  withRouter
)(User);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that TypeScript has troubles infer correct types for `compose` function. So it uses [most general form](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/b6e1586d382b7e1f8f27776c3f422ef59efcd33a/index.d.ts#L579) of `compose`, so result type is incorrect.

You can solve this problem by explicitly typing `compose`, but I suggest not to do so, as return type from `connect` is very complicated.

I suggest compose function 'by hand', like so

```
withRouter(
    connect(
        mapState,
        actionCreators
    )(User))
```